# mount / in wine as /

Tags: mount, wine, 32-bit

Now, wine mounts / folder as Z: drive, and in winecfg I can change it to another letter, but i need to mount it as is  / to /.(This behaviour was on other version of wine, I dont remember which).

This way I want to achieve launch of winebrowser to open native application associated with file. I checked - if path started with / it works, but if root folder mounted as disk, winebrowser doesn't recognize this path and does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It may be quite disturbing and I might be wrong but the behavior that you describe was maybe a bug of Wine (which may took a long time to be corrected).

Let me explain why :

Wine is a layer to Linux that helps windows programs to run under Linux. So the objective of Wine is to mimic Windows because if he does not do this then programs fails to run correctly.

Windows path works only in two modes : UNC (\Computer\path\something) and Drive letters (C:\Windows\System32)

Having the Unix/Linux path system under windows ( /. as you want to do) is against the laws of windows and so against Wine. Plus this is something weird because under Unix it refers to a dot file under the root folder (but you can't have it because the . has a special meaning and must be followed by at least a letter or number)

If I misunderstood you please provide more details.

Comment: I need this for total commander to be able to launch videos/music/graphics files using native applications.(I know its not a true way, but I tired of gnome commander/double commander/nautulus - they dont have and a half of features of tc, and main thing i decided to bring back tc through wine - it's stable program and doesn't crashes every 20 minutes(especially if I needed a lot of local network browsing/copying/replacing)
mounting point / is possible, cause I have used it for example in aimp when it also was launched from wine[but now i discovered deadbeef and happy)]

Comment: so you are looking to access / with total commander under wine. And if it's shown as / is it ok or it must be /. ?

Comment: trouble not in tc, but in winebrowser.exe(wine tool to launch native os application) - it doesn't convert virtual Z:\ path to /. But if i manually type in tc console "winebrowser.exe /home/user/picture.jpg" it works as desired, so task is to convert path to native, or to tell winebrowser to convert path.

Comment: did you try this : winebrowser file://z:\\path\\to\\file.png

Comment: not works :( I think easier will be to write own util launcher which will convert virtual path to native, anyway thanks for advices.

Comment: maybe this will help you (a little old but seem to be good) : http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-make-wine-open-links-in-your.html